# Should C++11 Move and Copy Assignment Operators return const?

Tags: c++11

Should C++11 Move and Copy Assignment Operators return const?

Example code:

```
const my_class& operator=(const my_class& other)
{
    // Copy the data
    my_class tmp(other);
    *this = std::move(tmp);

    return *this;
}


const my_class& operator=(my_class&& other)
{
    // Steal the data
    std::swap(my_data_length, other.my_data_length);
    std::swap(my_data, other.my_data);

    return *this;
}
```

For clarity:

```
class my_class
{

    protected:

    double *my_data;
    uint64_t my_data_length;
}
```

Notice the `const` on the return type. I usually put this without thinking, but is it really necessary? What does returning `const` prevent you from doing? (An example would be helpful here.)

Note one example was given but then it was removed. Can anyone comment on the following? `(a = b).non_const_member_function();`

Answer (score 2):

No, they definitely should not return a reference to const. A typical declaration is:

```
my_class& operator=(const my_class& other)
my_class& operator=(my_class&& other)
```

According to cpprefernce:

[CopyAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable)

[MoveAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveAssignable)

Returning `T&` for copy and move assignment is requirement to satisfy `CopyAssignable` and `MoveAssignable` concept

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Assignment operators and operators like `+=` e.t.c. should always return a reference to the class so that it can be assigned to again:

If it returns `const`, you cannot do the following do the fact the return object is immutable.

```
std::string str = "Hello";

(str = "Hello World") += "!";//assign value to hello world then append !
```

Returning `const&` still allows you to do functions that are `const` declared, but nothing that would modify the container, such as `=`, `+=`, `swap`, e.t.c.

Answer (score 0):

Well the return value can be used for chain assignment. So a const return would prevent a system like this: `(a = b) = c`. As `a=b` returns a const object.

Comment: `a = b = c` means `a = (b = c)`, which still works. Only `(a = b) = c` doesn't work when `=` returns `const`.

Comment: they are grouped right to left `(a = (b = c))`, so it's not the point

Comment: @hvd What would the code `(a = b) = c` actually do? Assign b to a, and then what? Assign c to a?

Comment: My mistake. Changed grouping.

Comment: Does it actually matter in this case though? Because if this code assigns b to a and then assigns c to a, then that is essentially equivalent to assigning c to a without b ever being there... so in this case, does it actually matter whether or not this compiles, because surely you would never want to do `(a = b) = c`? Still interesting example though.

Comment: @user3728501 Yes, exactly. It's not generally useful, but it's valid.